# Problem installing library in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-library

**I want to install Picasso Library in Android Studio:**

```
dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
***implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'***
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

}

**after sync gradle , it gave this warning :**

```
Failed to resolve: androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0
```

Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

Comment: Please check out [ask] to develop your question further.

Answer (score 0):

set this code in `build.gradle`

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
  
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}
```

I think you are in a boycott country and you can not use this product You must use a strong filter breaker to be able to install the package properly